# i have problems with django

Tags: python, django

i am trying to run my app with command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and its give me the error:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required;
>   you have %s.' % Database.**version**)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or
>   newer is required; you have 0.9.3.

Comment: You can not run your app with this commend. This commend is to run the Django server. What you are actually doing show me some code or explain what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Download mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)

cd to file folder

run:

```
pip install <file name>
```